# Django Python Show functions in html

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    def show_something(self):
        return "Foo Bar"
```

## views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .models import SomeModel


def some_view(request):
    instances = SomeModel.objects.all()  # queryset
    single_instance = instances.first()  # single object

    context = {
       'object_list' : instances,   # queryset
       'object' : single_instance  # single object
    }

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

## template

```
{% load static %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'img/logo.ico' %}" />

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="{% static "js/jquery-1.11.1.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/rango-jquery.js" %}"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false;}
        </script>
        <style>
            {% block style %}{% endblock style %}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="" oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false">  
        <div id="bar"></div>    

        {% for item in object_list %}  // accessing method through queryset

         {{ item.show_something }}

    {% endfor %}


    {{ object.show_something }}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from page import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.some_view, name="index")
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

That's the code have now, but it doesn't show me anything on the screen, it says going to return "Foo Bar" on the screen, but it doesn't, and i done the migrations

I don't know if explain myself enough, i hope you can help me, updated it so you can see better "ruddra"

And i want to show that function on my html page, how woulded it

SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problem? Do you mean you want to call the function from template?

Comment: Yes, call it from the html template

Comment: You can use template filters for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method is inside a model class, pass the instance of you model in HttpResponse and use Ginga to call the method.

```
from django.template import Template, Context

context = Context({‘my_model’: model_instance})
template = Template(“The method show prints {{my_model.show()}}”)
template.render(context)
```

If it’s a method defined outside the model,

```
from django.template import Template, Context
from models import show

template = Template(“The method show prints {{show()}}”)
template.render()
```

Comment: Where i put that?

Comment: Put this in views.py, in the method you’re using to render your template.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, you have a model like this:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models


class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # some fields

    def show_something(self):
        return "Foo Bar"
```

Now when you have a object method of a model class, you need to access it through an model instance. And that instance/instances needs to be sent to the Template from view. Like this(I will be sending both a single model instance and [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) to the template):

```
# views.py

from .models import SomeModel


def some_view(request):
    instances = SomeModel.objects.all()  # queryset
    single_instance = instances.first()  # single object

    context = {
       'object_list' : instances   # queryset
       'object' : single_instance  # single object
    }

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

And Finally in template, you can access the method like this:

```
// your_template.html

{% for item in object_list %}  // accessing method through queryset
     {{ item.show_something }}
{% endfor %}


{{ object.show_something }}  // accessing method form a single object
```

Comment: I get this; 

NameError at /
name 'SomeModel' is not defined

I tried put this in 'urls'

path('', views.some_view, name="index")

Comment: Mark here: instances = SomeModel.objects.all()  # queryset

Comment: @Alien69 In your question, you said you have a method in models. That is why I have put an example model. You should replace it with your own model and method.

Comment: Yeah, but, i wanted try this

Comment: @Alien69 in that case, make sure to write `SomeModel` in a `models.py`, then import it in `views.py`. I have also updated my answer to make things clearer.

Comment: sorry, i done everything but doesn't return anything on the page

Comment: Can you please share what you have done in your question?

Comment: Updated it, ruddra

Answer (score 0):

You can either call it from views as suggested by @Kshitij or you can create a custom template filter to call the method. Here is the documentation for [writing custom template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

In your case, you can create a custom template filter as:

```
@register.filter
def call_method(obj):
    return obj.show
```

Then in your template, you can use the filter as:

```
{{ obj|call_method }}
```

where obj is the object for your specified model which defines the method.

Make sure the method is defined inside the model. Using template filters makes it easier to call even the methods that expect some argument.

In case your method accepts an argument as:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def some_function(self, var):
        return var
```

Then you can easily create a template filter using:

```
@register.filter
def get_method(obj, v):
    return obj.some_function(v)
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ obj|get_method:'your parameter' }}
```

Comment: The filter where i put?

Comment: As I have provided the docs in my answer, it says that you need to create a folder named templatetags inside your app directory(where your models, views and templates for the app reside). Have a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout for better understanding